# Запятая между «и» и «когда»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, ссп

> Мне очень хотелось увидеться с бывшими одноклассниками, и, **когда
> наша встреча состоялась**, я спросил их, скучают ли они по школе.

Почему союз ***и*** не входит в выделенную часть? Выглядит странно такое обособление, особенно если ***и*** заменить на ***а***. Запятая здесь ставится в соответствии с каким-то правилом или "по логике"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Союз ***и*** соединяет два главных предложения: *Мне хотелось увидеться, и я спросил.*
У второго из них есть придаточное предложение с союзом ***когда***. Это придаточное можно удалить или переставить без потери смысла. С союзом ***а*** так не получится.

Если бы после придаточного стояла частица ***то***, запятая не ставилась бы:
*Мне очень хотелось увидеться с бывшими одноклассниками, и когда наша встреча состоялась, то я спросил их, скучают ли они по школе.*

Такие случаи описаны в правилах:
[**Постановка запятой при встрече союзов**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188) (Грамота.ру),
[**Запятая на стыке двух союзов**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140) (справочник Розенталя).